# How to convert Datetime to Date and use in Where clause?

Tags: sql-server

What am I missing I need to convert datetime to just date and use it in a between statement in a where clause.

CreatedDate
2016-07-19 16:00:19.710

```
 WHERE convert(Date,CreatedDate) >='2016-06-01' AND convert(Date,CreatedDate) <= '2016-06-31'
```

I am getting conversion failed when converting date and/or Time from character string.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as string? You probably have invalid data (or different formats) since you get the error.

Comment: what would be the correct syntax to change datetime to date only?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can use try_convert, but still, fix your datatypes

Comment: explain what? Don't store dates as character strings, which, based on the error message you must be doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cast(CreatedDate as Date)` to convert. But I don't think you need to convert in this case to compare.

Just do:

`WHERE CreatedDate between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-31'`
should be fine

Comment: No that still requiring conversion

Comment: tried the cast and it still failed:  "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: I think you might have some invalid data format in your CreatedDate column which makes it unable to convert. could you do `WHERE ISDATE(CreatedDate) = 0` and see what rows it return?

Answer (score 0):

thanks it turns out the I need to formate the search criteria to include date and time where CreatedDate>= '2016-07-01 00:00:00.000'AND CreatedDate<= '2016-07-30 00:00:00.000'